# HBase batch get with spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to fetch data from HBase based on a list of row keys, in the API document there is a method called get(List gets), I am trying to use that, however the compiler is complaining something like this, does anyone had this experiance

```
overloaded method value get with alternatives: (x$1: java.util.List[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get])Array[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result] <and> (x$1: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get)org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result cannot be applied to (List[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get])
```

The code I tried.

```
val keys: List[String] = df.select("id").rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
   val gets:List[Get]=keys.map(x=> new Get(Bytes.toBytes(x)))
   val results = hTable.get(gets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using JavaConvert to make it java.util.List, then it worked

```
val gets:List[Get]=keys.map(x=> new Get(Bytes.toBytes(x)))
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
   val getJ=gets.asJava
   val results = hTable.get(getJ).toList
```

Comment: In this case where you are using Spark

Answer (score 0):

your gets is of type List[Get]. Here List is of Scala type. However, HBase get request expects Java List type. You can use Seq[Get] instead of List[Get] as Scala Seq is more closer to Java List.
So, you can try with below code:

```
val keys: List[String] = df.select("id").rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
   val gets:Seq[Get]=keys.map(x=> new Get(Bytes.toBytes(x)))
   val results = hTable.get(gets)
```

Comment: Nope , Seq didn't work. I ended up using JavaConvert

Comment: I am not sure why it didn't work with Seq. But I do agree, JavaConverter should also do the job. Good for you.